# Firebase RealtimeDatabase with .NET Core

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, .net-core, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to send/retrieve data to a firebase-realtimedatabase using .NET Core.
It's just server-to-server communication. No other fancy authentication needed for users.
I have been using [FireSharp](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp) but it uses app-secrets/tokens which Google says are deprecated.

Now I am using the following (with Firesharp)

```
var client = new FirebaseClient(new FirebaseConfig
{
   BasePath = //my url,
   AuthSecret = // my secret,
});

client.OnAsync($"my/url/",
        changed: (sender, args, context) => DoStuff(args));
```

It works but after some time the token becomes too old / invalid. I'd like to use refresh-tokens. Firesharp does not support something like this and the Google docs are lacking .NET documentation.
[Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) are saying the following:

```
var myApp = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
{
    Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("my-app.json"),
});

var myAppAuth = FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(myApp);
```

But then what? How to get the realtime-database reference so I can listen to changes? What to do to get an access-token or refresh-token?

Comment: `FirebaseApp` is from the `FirebaseAdmin` package, and it doesn't support realtime database. Switching your code to use refresh tokens doesn't really solve your problem unless Firesharp also have the support to periodically refresh the access token, and re-establish the SSE connection to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess I'll have to use a workaround with Firesharp. It's still disappointing that Google does not provide decent docs and sdk for realtime database (for .NET).

Answer (score 0):

```
 var client = new 
RestClient("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/<PATH_TO_DATA>.json");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <REFRESH_TOKEN>");
var response = client.Execute(request);
var data = response.Content;
```

check this out

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).